# Redirect extra url to Multisite in folder

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess

I have a multisite that uses subfolders (for instance domainname.com/mysite).

I would like to have this site also available through for instance domainname.com/mysite2.

Is there a way to do this through .htaccess?

Comment: So you're trying to redirect *...com/mysite2* to *...com/mysite* ?

Comment: Both should have the same content. I found out how to redirect the URL, but it would be better if /mysite2 stayed in the URL

Comment: Having two sites with identical content seems not to be a good idea at all. Especially search engines like Google will punish you because of duplicate content...

Comment: Actually, I'm trying this because I have two subsites (directory) which are both multi language (WPML). Everything is translatable, except the site slug in the URL.

Comment: Did you check [Translating Page Slugs](http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-page-slugs/)? We can only help you, if you're asking a clear question :)

Comment: Thanks Sven, but translating the Page slugs (and pretty much everything else) is fine. The only thing WPML can't manage is the (directory) name of a sub site.